# API to list top level domains

Tags: rest

Anyone recommend any good web service to query and list all possible TLDs.

I'm currently looking at http://domainapi.com/ right now. I can query TLDs, but I cant find a way to list them. If anyone can think of any other good examples that have updated TLDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information directly from IANA.  The data is here http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db and the HTML looks fairly easy to scrape.

Comment: thanks. if I can avoid scraping I'd like to. Also, they dont seem to have .co.uk on there. I know I could check for .co and .uk, but I would like to validate people entering .com.uk.... or any other incorrect domain.

Comment: You can't "check for .co and .uk" because the .co in .co.uk is not a TLD.

Comment: @madphp If you're looking for a list using a looser definition of "TLD" (i.e. one that includes .co.uk), try https://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 10):

Looks like ICANN does provide a computer-readable list of all valid TLDs:
https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt (found via [this page](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en))

I'm not sure how frequently it's updated, but the couple times I've checked it's not been older than 24 hours.

I don't know how often you can query it without bothering them, so I wouldn't do it too often. It's not like the list changes frequently.

Comment: Be careful!! Google Safe Browsing could flag your domain if it is "rare" like .online o.dev ,etc

Comment: @JRichardsz This question is for people wanting to get the list of TLDs. It's not for domain owners. So while this is helpful if you own a domain, this isn't really relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API to query and get a full list of the TLDs:
https://rapidapi.com/casper15155/api/tld1/

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer available

Comment: @jkmartindale I am the author behind the API. I have disabled it because I got very little traffic. Let me know if this is something that you still want to use.